# PDF spec. language needs to be able to conviniently read text ou of <.......> Tj

Tags: pdf

The need is to check if a text is really as expected, but found that the uncompressed PDF obj has it being human unreadable

```
 BT
 /F4 32 Tf
 1 0 0 -1 32 31 Tm
 <003900030027005200460058005000480051005700440057004C00520051> Tj
 ET
```

as plain english text even after converting it to Ascii/UTF-8 e.g. by

```
$  xxd -r -ps <<<'003900030027005200460058005000480051005700440057004C00520051'
9'RFXPHQWDWLRQ
```

then how is definitive steps to obtain the real text as printed on PDF from such PDF spec. lang., so can conveniently trace any uncompressed PDF, how actually working mechanism of PDF text content ?

Help sincerely thanks
EDIT:
/F4 traced to be

```
<< /BaseFont /AAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT /DescendantFonts [ 14 0 R ] /Encoding /Identity-H /Subtype
        /Type0 /ToUnicode 412 0 R /Type /Font >>
```

Hope it might give any help

Comment: You need to read the PDF specification.  That's a string of 15 characters, with codes 0x0039, 0x0003, 0x0027 etc.  If those were Unicode code points, it would be "9"RFXPHQDWLRQ", but PDF files use lookup tables to save space, so they might not actually be Unicode.  Note that there are already very good tools for scraping the text from a PDF.

Comment: *"That's a string of 15 characters, with codes 0x0039, 0x0003, 0x0027 etc."* - Well, *most likely* it is, considering all those `00`s and what one commonly sees in such streams. Theoretically, though, it could also be something else, e.g. a single-byte encoding that maps `00` to a character used at every other position (like a space character in spaced out style). Essentially, therefore, you'll have to look up the font **F4** shortly before and check its **Encoding** (and also possibly its **CIDToGIDMap** and **CIDSystemInfo**), and even then the information may not suffice for text extraction

Comment: *"then how is definitive steps to obtain the real text as printed on PDF from such PDF"* - See ISO 32000-2 section 9.10 "Extraction of text content" (D'oh!) Execute your check as described there.

Comment: Your edit shows `/Encoding /Identity-H`, so there essentially the internal encoding of the embedded font program is used. That font program is embedded as part of the descendant font in object 14. There is a shortcut for your requirements, though: the **ToUnicode** entry points to a map in object 412 that contains a mapping from character codes to Unicode.